# iOS swift , video output not centering inside the UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I got this video playing inside a sublayer of the view , but the video keeps popping underneath the `UIView` not inside of it any solution ?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player : AVPlayer? = nil
    var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer? = nil
    var asset : AVAsset? = nil
    var playerItem: AVPlayerItem? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let videoURLWithPath = "http://selevision9890-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/219323/98906/1.m3u8"
        let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)
        asset = AVAsset(URL: videoURL!) as AVAsset
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset!)
        videoView.frame = self.view.frame
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
        playerLayer!.frame = videoView.frame
        videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

        player!.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

normal view:

[image: ScreenShot]

(from here: http://prnt.sc/e33dhf)

rotated view:

[image: ScreenShot]

(from here: http://prnt.sc/e33djs)

Comment: why are you given playerlayer frame twice  
playerLayer!.frame = videoView.frame
    playerLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame

Comment: the second one is to take the whole frame of the view without it its being smaller in width

Comment: may i know the frame of videoView

Comment: the video is a live stream i don't want to add an exact size for it i simply want to to be centered inside the uiview

Comment: Try this videoview,frame=self.view.frame and  videoView.center = self.view.center

Comment: http://prnt.sc/e3329c this is a screenshot of my problem

Comment: @HassanKalach Are you using any auto-layout on the container view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to ditch avplayer and use avplayerviewcontroller and it worked fine thank you all

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let avPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var avPlayer:AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let movieUrl:NSURL? = NSURL( string :"http://selevision9890-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/219323/98906/1.m3u8")

        if let url = movieUrl{
            self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL : url )
            self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.presentViewController(self.avPlayerViewController, animated: true) { 
            self.avPlayerViewController.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please inline your code (mark you code and tap on `{}` so that it includes also the first and the last line (see the code change history)

Comment: thank you for your modification i am still new and trying my best .

Answer (score 2):

Move this code into `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` - in `viewDidLoad` the frames are not correct yet. The view is resized to fit the screen size after `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Delete this line `playerLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame`.

Comment: after deleting this code i got the same result nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Set PlayerLayer videogravity

```
let videoURLWithPath = "http://selevision9890-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/219323/98906/1.m3u8"
let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL! as URL)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
playerLayer.frame =  videoView.frame
playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
videoView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
player!.play()
```

Comment: i am using xcode 7.3 this code is not working withit specialy the URL thing

Comment: and the playerlayer videogravity does not change the fact that the video is not showing inside the uiview

Comment: in your screen shot video is playing at bottom of screen you want it to show in middle?

Comment: try to give different color for videoview background , Will you tell me the frame of your video view

Comment: that's correct in the middle but inside the white space of the uiview

Comment: tell me the videoview frame

Comment: you mean the size of the videwView ?!

Comment: set videoview.frame = self.view.frame then try

Comment: what is the view with whitecolor is it video view?

Comment: that dint make any diffrence but i made the uiview fill the whole page with constraints so now on the original layout the video gets centered correctly , but i rotate the phone i get a weird layout i will attach 2 new pictures in couple minutes

Comment: playerLayer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI)) add this line and let me know

Comment: same result simply the video turned out flipped in both layouts

Comment: you are adding player layer on white view which is videoview , Here video view frame is small where you have given  playerLayer?.frame = self.view.layer.frame remove this line and check

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem. I went with subclassing UIView like this:

```
import UIKit

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {
var playerLayer: CALayer?

override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer)
    playerLayer?.frame = self.bounds
  }
}
```

and use it for setting up a video like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: VideoPlayerView!

func setupVideoOnView() {
    var player = AVPlayer(URL: mediaURL! as NSURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = self.videoPlayer.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.videoPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.videoPlayer.playerLayer = playerLayer

}
```

That did a trick with wrong frame.

Comment: you are using class videoplayerview whats that ?!

Comment: I wrote how this class looks like.

Comment: i have pasted all my code can you be more presize on what i should do and in case i can asheve the same result using avplayerviewcontroller

Comment: For your `@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!` use class I provided which is `VideoPlayerView` by setting it in storyboard then make an outlet `@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: VideoPlayerView!` and then setup this view with my `setupVideoOnView()` function.

Comment: i could not find anything related to this @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: VideoPlayerView! maybe your using a new version xcode i am using 7.3

Comment: In storyboard you need to change class of your UIView in which you want to play your video to my class `VideoPlayerView` and then make an outlet by ctrl dragging to your code it will become `@IBOutlet weak var videoPlayer: VideoPlayerView!` then.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to have your view like a canvas and basically draw the AVPlayerViewController on top of it:

```
@IBOutlet weak var layerVideoView: UIImageView!
guard let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "santana", ofType: "mp4") else { return debugPrint("video not found") }
let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: url)

let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
playerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: layerVideoView.frame.origin.x, y: layerVideoView.frame.origin.y, width: layerVideoView.frame.width, height: layerVideoView.frame.height)
self.addChild(playerController)
self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
```

LayerVideoView is an image view, but you can use just a UIView if that suits. Its is important to add constraints in the Storyboard to your View because your Video Player will mimic the shape of your View.